# ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'width' must be length 0 or scalar

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

Trying to plot silhouette plots but am getting the below error.

Code:

```
    plt.barh(range(y_ax_lower, y_ax_upper), 
             c_silhouette_vals,
             height= 1.0, 
             edgecolor = 'none',
             color = color)
```

c_silhouette_vals is an array.

Error:

```
C:****-
packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in bar(self, left, height, width, bottom, 
**kwargs)
   2039         if len(width) != nbars:
   2040             raise ValueError("incompatible sizes: argument 'width' "
-> 2041                              "must be length %d or scalar" % nbars)
   2042         if len(bottom) != nbars:
   2043             raise ValueError("incompatible sizes: argument 'bottom' "

ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'width' must be length 0 or scalar
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of c_silhouette_vals ?

Comment: c_silhouette_vals.shape  -->  (50, )

Comment: OK, and what are the values of y_ax_lower and y_ax_upper?

Comment: y_ax_lower = 0 and y_ax_upper = 50

Comment: Weird. ```c = np.random.rand(50); plt.barh(range(0,50),c,height=1.0, edgecolor='none')``` works for me. Did you check the dimensions immediately before the function call?

Comment: If you didn't find an answer, I only get this error when `range(y_ax_lower, y_ax_upper)` is 0 length - I would make sure those values are set properly. Ideally `print` them right before you call `plt.barh`.